# Listbox listvariable.get() returns tuple, but is handled like string?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tuples

Working within a class, I am trying to get the selected items in a listbox, but when I apply the selection indices, it seems the tuple has turned into a string.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    # <---snip--->
    self.part_no = tk.StringVar()
    self.part_listbox = tk.Listbox(self, listvariable=self.part_no, selectmode='multiple')
    # <---snip--->

def load_part(self):

    part_list = self.part_no.get() # tuple of strings
    selection = self.part_listbox.curselection() # tuple of integers

    load_list = [part_list[item] for item in selection] # list of characters???
    print(part_list, selection, load_list)
```

Selecting the first three values (and pressing the button with the load_part command) gives me the output:

```
('101', '201', '301', '401', '501') (0, 1, 2) ['(', "'", '1']
```

I expected:

```
('101', '201', '301', '401', '501') (0, 1, 2) ['101', '201', '301']
```

Can someone clue me in on what's going on here?

Python 3.8.2, Tkinter 8.6

Comment: part_list is a string representation of a tuple not a tuple.

Comment: What makes you think that `StringVar.get()` should return a tuple instead of a string?

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` to really get a tuple of strings i.e. `part_list = ast.literal_eval(self.part_no.get())`

Comment: Thanks @AlbinPaul, that, of course, is it.

Comment: @quamrana, because I misinterpreted another post here on Stack Overflow and the output looked like a tuple, which enforced my misconception.

Comment: Is there any value in keeping this post, or should I just delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Because the premise is false.

listvariable.get() returns a string, not a tuple.

Lesson learned: Always double-check the object type.